# Where does `service` node go in a firebase database.rules.json

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-cli

Where does the service element get put in a `database.rules.json` file used by the firebase client, which is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
  }
}
```

I'm assuming the above applies to both Cloud Firestore and real time database?

I have a Cloud Firestore rule I'd like to keep in the json file so that it can be source controlled and deployed automatically.  Here's the rule as shown in firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    match /photos {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == user.id)
    }
  }
}
```

How do I update my `database.rules.json` file to start to keep it in sync?  Do I need to add a cloud.firestore element under rules?  Where does it go?  Are firestore rules kept in a completely separate file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put these rules in a separate file named `firestore.rules`.

The first set of rules (i.e. the ones in `database.rules.json`) in only for the Real Time Database.

Comment: Ah yes, running `firebase init firestore` added those files

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase Realtime Database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) are completely different than [Cloud Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  You can't have one file for both, and there is no automated process to keep them in sync, whatever that means for you.  When you run `firebase init`, tell it that you want to init both Realtime Database and Firestore, and it will suggest names of different files for the rules.